# Problema ao listar dados de arquivo de texto em c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Boa noite a todos,

Tenho que entregar um trabalho na faculdade , o mesmo esta sendo feito em C++.

Como é a primeira vez que me deparo com esta linguagem , estou com um problema em umas das parte do programa.

Segue :

No arquivo de texto , os dados são gravados da seguinte maneira:

- 1|henrique felix|4324342|23424-5|23/01/1997|Rua dos
  andradas,483|centro|bebedouro|1799999999|hfelixmiguell@gmail.com
- 2|Leonardo Felix|32312312|34235|17/02/1997|Rua dos
  andradas|centro|bebedouro|1799999999|leo.foda

Eu consigo listar normalmente esse dados , mas o trabalho exige que tenha uma opção de busca ,ou seja , o usuario informa um valor e o sistema busca no arquivo os dados.

Abaixo , segue a minha função para buscar os clientes cadastrados , ela deve ter 4 opções : 1 - buscar pelo codigo ,2 - buscar pelo nome , 3 - buscar pelo cpf - Essas 3 partes estão funcionando corretamente - 4 - buscar por cidade ( aqui , deve trazer o resultado de todos clientes de x cidade informada.

Ex: sao paulo -> ira listar todos os clientes de sao paulo

Mas  , empaquei nessa ultima parte.

```html
void buscarClientes() {

 system("cls");

 Cliente cliente;
 fstream arquivo;
 string codCliente;

 int cod, i;
 string nome, cpf, cidade;

 cout << "--------------------------------------------------------\n";
 cout << "-------------------- Buscar clientes por: --------------\n\n";
 cout << "1 - Código | 2 - Nome | 3 - CPF | 4 - Cidade \n\n";

 cout << "Opção': ";
 cin >> i;

 rewind(stdin); //limpa o buffer do teclado

 arquivo.open("dados/clientes.txt", ios::in);
 if (arquivo.is_open()) {

  while (!arquivo.eof()) {

   getline(arquivo, codCliente, '|');

   if (codCliente != "") {

    cliente.codigo = stoi(codCliente);   //converte a string codCliente para inteiro
    getline(arquivo, cliente.nome, '|');
    getline(arquivo, cliente.cpf, '|');
    getline(arquivo, cliente.rg, '|');
    getline(arquivo, cliente.data_nasc, '|');
    getline(arquivo, cliente.endereco, '|');
    getline(arquivo, cliente.bairro, '|');
    getline(arquivo, cliente.cidade, '|');
    getline(arquivo, cliente.telefone, '|');
    getline(arquivo, cliente.email,'|');

    if (i == 1) {

     cout << "Informe o código do cliente: ";
     cin >> cod;

     rewind(stdin); //limpa o buffer do teclado

     if (cliente.codigo == cod) {

      cout << "\nCódigo: " << cliente.codigo << " || Nome: " << cliente.nome << "\n";
      cout << "CPF: " << cliente.cpf << " || RG: " << cliente.rg << "\n";
      cout << "Data de nascimento: " << cliente.data_nasc << "\n";
      cout << "Endereço: " << cliente.endereco << "\n";
      cout << "Bairro: " << cliente.bairro << " || Cidade: " << cliente.cidade << "\n";
      cout << "Telefone: " << cliente.telefone << "\n";
      cout << "E-mail: " << cliente.email;
      cout << "\n--------------------------------";

      system("pause > null"); //para a execução para poder exibir o cliente encontrado
      break; //Termina a execução do while, sem precisar ler todo o arquivo
     }

    }else if (i == 2) {

     cout << "Informe o nome do cliente: ";
     getline(cin,nome);

     transform(nome.begin(), nome.end(), nome.begin(), ::tolower); //converte as letras maiusculas
                      //para minusculas
     if (cliente.nome == nome) {

      cout << "\nCódigo: " << cliente.codigo << " || Nome: " << cliente.nome << "\n";
      cout << "CPF: " << cliente.cpf << " || RG: " << cliente.rg << "\n";
      cout << "Data de nascimento: " << cliente.data_nasc << "\n";
      cout << "Endereço: " << cliente.endereco << "\n";
      cout << "Bairro: " << cliente.bairro << " || Cidade: " << cliente.cidade << "\n";
      cout << "Telefone: " << cliente.telefone << "\n";
      cout << "E-mail: " << cliente.email;
      cout << "\n--------------------------------";

      system("pause > null"); //para a execução para poder exibir o cliente encontrado
      break; //Termina a execução do while, sem precisar ler todo o arquivo

     }else {

      cout << "Cliente não encontradado! Tente novamente!\n";
     }

    }else if (i == 3) {

     cout << "Informe o cpf do cliente: ";
     cin >> cpf;

     if (cliente.cpf == cpf) {

      cout << "\nCódigo: " << cliente.codigo << " || Nome: " << cliente.nome << "\n";
      cout << "CPF: " << cliente.cpf << " || RG: " << cliente.rg << "\n";
      cout << "Data de nascimento: " << cliente.data_nasc << "\n";
      cout << "Endereço: " << cliente.endereco << "\n";
      cout << "Bairro: " << cliente.bairro << " || Cidade: " << cliente.cidade << "\n";
      cout << "Telefone: " << cliente.telefone << "\n";
      cout << "E-mail: " << cliente.email;
      cout << "\n--------------------------------";

      system("pause > null"); //para a execução para poder exibir o cliente encontrado
      break; //Termina a execução do while, sem precisar ler todo o arquivo
     }

    }//if opçao 3
    else if (i == 4) {

     cout << "Informe a cidade do cliente: ";
     cin >> cidade;

     cout << "\n---- CLIENTES da cidade de:" << cidade << "---------\n\n";


    } //if de cidade

    else {

     cout << "Opção invalida!! Tente novamente!!\n";
    }

   }//IF cod cliente != null

  }//while arquivo aberto

  arquivo.close(); // fecha o arquivo

 }
 else {
  cout << "Não foi possível abrir o arquivo!";
 }
}
```

Como posso fazer para listar os dados ?

Desde já , grato

Comment: Olá, Henrique. Poderia explicar melhor qual parte está te causando dúvidas? Me parece que você não conseguiu pensar é no algoritmo, já que envolve buscar dados que batem com um valor potencialmente repetido. É isso?

Comment: boa tarde @Pablo , desculpe a demora em responder. Exatamente isso , ja pensei em como fazer  , mas em nenhuma das tentativas obtive sucesso. Todo o resto do programa esta pronto , pois devo apresenta-lo ainda esta semana , estou devendo somente esta parte para concluir.

Comment: @HenriqueFelix Se puder postar a resposta caso tenha consigo, isso ajudará a comunidade.